# How to encode text when generating an xml file using rythm

Tags: rythm

I have to encode text in an error message tag while generating an xml file. My tag is
"ErrorMessage" any text with special character suchs as <>#$%^& "/ErrorMessage". Is there a way to encode those special characters when generating file using rythm template engine?

Answer (score 0):

They should be escaped automatically unless you use .raw() extension. If some chars are not escaped properly please submit an issue on github

Comment: No, I am not using any raw() extensions. I am using rythm-engine 1.0.1 version. Please let me know this version provides escape automatically.

Comment: yes it escape automatically if the template name has ".xml" suffix

Comment: I am still facing same issues with special characters. Can you please suggest on how I can solve this problem?